# Are my fasts accepted if I kept them without doing sehri?

Tags: halal-haram, ramadan

While I was in college I had kept most of my ramazan fast without doing the sehri (the eating session before the fajr adhan and keeping of the fast).

Questions:

1. Are my fasts valid and accepted if I keep them without doing sehri?
2. Is it allowed to have eggs in sehri?

Comment: Please separate out the questions into 2 different question. Good to keep question specific and helps expand the site by separating out question that can stand alone by them selves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the provided facts the validity of your fast would depend on the following:

- if you didn't do the niyat to fast for the entire month of ramazan then

  - if you didn't do the niyat of fast before the adhan of fajr then

    - if you woke

      - before zuhr adhan and did the niyat then your fast were valid
      - after zuhr adhan and did the niyat then you have to give qadha of those fasts
  - else if you did niyat before the adhan of fajr  and slept then the fasts are in order
- else if you had done the niyat to fast for the entire month of ramzan then all your fasts were in order

Doing sehr could be a sunnat (not sure) but the validity of the fast doesn't depend on it, instead it's the niyat/intention that matters.

To emphasis:

> It is not necessary for a person to pass the niyyat for fasting through his mind or to say that he would be fasting on the following day. In fact, it is sufficient for him to decide that in obedience to the command of Allah he will not perform from the time of Adhan for Fajr prayers up to Maghrib, any act which may invalidate the fast.

Your fasts were valid or not we can deduce but whether they were accepted or not is solely in His authority.

Although, it would have been preferred and recommended that you ask the second question in another post/question but if you intend not to (not recommended) then the answer to it is that anything that is halal can be eaten for sehri. And since eggs, provided they are of halal birds, are halal therefore there is no restriction.

Source: Website of Ayatullah Sayyid Ali Husaini Sistani, Islamic Laws, [Fasting » Niyyat for fasting](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2262/), rule #1559, 1560, 1563, 1568, 1569.

Answer (score 5):

Doing sehri before fasting is a sunnah of our beloved Prophet S.A. Many scholars said that without sehri, the fasting could be considered as a fast, but the rewards will not be similar to the fasts with Sahar.

So, the answer is **YES**, fasting without sahr is considered as a fast. But, accepting the fast is with the hands of Allah(Subh). He looks in to all our actions in fasting including our thoughts.

There are a [lot of benefits in taking sahar food](http://www.haqislam.org/virtues-of-sehri/) that you may already knew.

There is nothing mentioned in any authentic references about eggs in Sehri. So, eggs are allowed to eat at sahar time.

Answer (score 0):

Many scholars said that without very much fasting could be considered a fast, but the rewards will not be similar to fasting with Sahar. So, the answer is YES, fasting without Sahr is considered a fast. But to accept fasting is with the hands of Allah (Subh). He looks at all our actions in fasting, including our thoughts.